# Grails Spring Security use email to login

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

My User domain class extends SecUser.

User has a property 'email'.

Spring security uses SecUser's 'username' to login.

I need to use 'email' to login. Is there a way to do this?

Edit (from the accepted answer):

I deleted SecUser's username property and added email property.

Then I added this line to Config.groovy:

grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RTFM my friend :)

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#4.1%20Person%20Class

```
userLookup.usernamePropertyName 'username'  User class username field
```

Add to Config.grooy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email'
```

newer versions of grails are using a prefix of

`grails.plugin.springsecurity` instead of  `grails.plugins.springsecurity`

Comment: First, I modified the line that the answer mentions in a config file of the plugin. Obviusly, that file was not versionated.
Then, I realized that I had to override the configuration in the Config.groovy file. I added the following:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'

Comment: fyi, in more recent versions of spring security, the prefix has changed. "Your security configuration settings use the old prefix 'grails.plugins.springsecurity' but must now use 'grails.plugin.springsecurity'"

Comment: Thanks @EdJ I added that to my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're also using the Spring Security UI plugin be aware that the default text for forgotten password and user registration emails reference the username field.

You can override them like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.register.emailBody = 'Hi \$user.firstName...'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.forgotPassword.emailBody = 'Hi \$user.firstName...'
```